# How to enable anti-aliasing for a polyline drawn with WPF StreamGeometry?

Tags: wpf, geometry, drawing, antialiasing

I need to draw a polyline into a DrawingVisual. I'm using StreamGeometry for performance reasons. The problem I have is that I can't figure out how to enable anti-aliasing. I can't find any method or property on StreamGeometry or on DrawingContext for anti-aliasing control.

The code below is in IronPython, but it shouldn't matter:

```
geometry = StreamGeometry()
context = geometry.Open()
context.BeginFigure(Point(10, 10), False, False)
context.LineTo(Point(100, 100), True, False)
context.LineTo(Point(200, 300), True, False)
context.Close()

dv = DrawingVisual()
dc = dv.RenderOpen()
dc.DrawGeometry(None, Pen(Brushes.Blue, 1), geometry)
dc.Close()
```

Answer (score 2):

To disable anti-aliasing you could use [RenderOptons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms635510%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class, with the static method [SetEdgeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.setedgemode%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) it's possible to determine how the edges of non-text drawing primitives of your DependencyObject are rendered.

```
RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(MyDependencyObject, EdgeMode.Aliased)
```

Hope this help.